# LocationManager sends in background when connected to computer but when disconnected it stops sending..?

Tags: ios, swift, location

I am able to have the location manager update the location properly in the background but only when the phone is connected to my macbook]:

In pList I have ***NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription*** value as well as the required background modes of ***App registers for location updates*** and ***App downloads content from the network***

In the AppDelegate I lazy load the locationManager, then after the viewcontroller gets initialized, i call **locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()**

```
lazy var locationManager:CLLocationManager! = {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        return manager
    }()



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        // Add another annotation to the map.
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate


        var latitude:String = annotation.coordinate.latitude.description
        var longitude:String = annotation.coordinate.longitude.description


        print("new location...\(latitude) - \(longitude)")
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Standard location updates are not permitted while the app is in the background (unless the app is a navigation app and registers for background operation; but it has to be a navigation app where it's truly needed for the app to run, not just because you'd like it to). It works when connected to the computer, because that artificially keeps the app running in background where it otherwise would not.

Comment: If it's not a true navigation app, you can start significant change service, which does run after the app is suspended.

Comment: its main functionality is displaying locations of different objects but it sends the coordinates to a server, is that a no-no?

Comment: Apple's concern is that standard location services can drain a user's battery very quickly. Either significant change services or region monitoring sounds like it is more applicable in your case.